# Como: validar mediante textBox existencia de un registro en base de datos. C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Quisiera saber:

¿Como validar desde un textBox la existencia de un registro guardado en base de datos?

Es decir, escribir en el textBox el nombre del registro y al pulsar el botón "Buscar", me salga un mensaje donde me indica que el registro existe.

Esto es lo que he hecho.

Y esta en mi boton "Buscar":

```
        using (ProductosEF _bdVentas = new ProductosEF())
        {
            Producto _Producto = new Producto();
            var BuscarProducto = _bdVentas.BusquedaProductos(textBox8.Text.Trim()).ToList();

                txtcodei.Text = BuscarProducto.FirstOrDefault().codigo_interno;
                txtcodebar.Text = BuscarProducto.FirstOrDefault().codigo_barra;
                txtdescripcion.Text = BuscarProducto.FirstOrDefault().descripcion;
                txtmarca.Text = BuscarProducto.FirstOrDefault().marca;
                txttamaño.Text = BuscarProducto.FirstOrDefault().tamaño;
                txtcosto.Text = BuscarProducto.FirstOrDefault().costo.ToString();
                txtprecio.Text = BuscarProducto.FirstOrDefault().precio.ToString();
```

*Funciona de esta manera:*

Escribo en el textBox el codigo, pulso el boton, y luego me trae los registros asociados al codigo. Lo que quiero saber es:

**Como: Valido que, si existe el codigo me muestre un mensaje de existencia, de lo contrario que me habilite mis campos correspondientes para crear el nuevo producto.**

Comment: Revise como formular preguntas, ¿qué ha intentado hasta el momento?, ¿que código ha hecho?

Comment: con un if si el tamaño de la lista es 0 no lo podria hacer?

Comment: Puede ejemplificar la sugerencia.

Comment: if (BuscarProducto.Lengt ==0) { //no encontro habilitar para insercion} else { // encontro registros mostrarlos para edicion si se requiere]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero haces una consulta a la base de datos con el dato del TextBox y luego:

```
       public bool ValidarProducto(BuscarProducto bp)
    {
      bool existe=false;
     try
    {
         if(bp.count()>0)
         {
           existe=true;
         }
    }
    Catch(Exception ex)
    {
      throw;
    }
  return existe;
  }
```

despues de que te devuelva el booleano puedes mirar que muestras como mensaje para que el usuario se entere.

```
if(ValidarProducto(buscproc))
{
  messagebox.show("El producto ya existe pruebe con un código diferente.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que no dices si ya tienes el metodo para la edicion y que utlizas para editar los datos si son textBox y un boton de editar puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
if (BuscarProducto.Lengt ==0) {
     //no encontro habilitar para insercion
     textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
     //suponiendo que tienes todo esto desactivado por que no explicas y asi activas todos tus edit textBox y puedes habilitar el boton de editar 
    button1.Enabled = true;
    MessageBox.Show("El producto ya existe");
    //y ya llenas el formulario y cuando lo edites los desactivas en el boton de agregar registro.
    } 
    else { 
     // encontro registros mostrarlos para edicion si se requiere
     textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
     //suponiendo que tienes todo esto desactivado por que no explicas y asi 
     activas todos tus edit textBox y puedes habilitar el boton de editar 
    button2.Enabled = true;
    MessageBox.Show("El producto no existe");
    //y ya llenas el formulario y cuando lo edites los desactivas en el boton de editar
    }
```

no se si te sirva por que por lo que entendi lo que querias era eso

Comment: private void btn_buscarProducto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox8.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ingrese Código de barra.","¡Advertencia!",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                return;
            }    //Ese es mi método y dentro de el esta lo que escribí arriba, al inicio.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes realizar de la Siguiente manera al momento que das Click en tu Boton buscar ejecutas algun Metodo que realize esta accion y te retorne un booleano si esta o no esta en la consulta, yo lo tengo ya algo simplificado pero te lo comparto espero te sirva de algo si tienes dudas comentame.. este metodo recive un consulta SQL con un Count(*)

asi lo utilizo

```
if (Existe("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TU_TABLA) == false)
{
// LOGICA 
}
```

Metodo :

Metodo

```
public static bool Existe(string txtSQL)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(txtSQL, Conex);
            Conectar();
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            if (count == 0)  
            {
                Conex.Close();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                Conex.Close();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Conex.Close();
            return false;   
        }
    }
```